# Find all $\alpha$ such that integral $\int\limits_0^1 \frac{ \cosh(\alpha x) - \ln(1+x^2)-1}{(8-x^3)^\frac{1}{3}-2}\,dx$ converges

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

Find all parameters $\alpha$ such that integral
$$
\int_{0}^{1}{\cosh\left(\alpha x\right) - \ln\left(1 + x^{2}\right) - 1 \over \left(8 - x^{3}\right)^{1/3} - 2}\,\mathrm{d}x
$$
converges. If we use Maclaurin series we can reduce it to
$\displaystyle
\int_{0}^{1}{1 \over x}\,{\left(\alpha^{2} - 2\right) + \mathrm{o}\left(1\right) \over 1 + \mathrm{o}\left(1\right)}\,\mathrm{d}x
$.

But what next $?$.

Comment: It's probably best to Taylor expand more terms than what you have. Then you can use $p$ test to determine how many need to vanish.

Comment: @NinadMunshi I tried, but got nothing.

Comment: It would be $\pm \sqrt{2}$, right?  I cannot think of another possibility.

Comment: @RonGordon yes.

Answer (score 1):

**Partial answer.** The Laurent series of the integrand is
$$f_\alpha(z):= \frac{\cosh(\alpha z) - \log(1+z^2) - 1}{\sqrt[3]{8-z^3}-2}= -\frac{6(\alpha^2-2)}{z} + \mathcal O(z),$$
in an annular region surrounding $z=0$. The annular region can be even taken to be $\mathbb C \setminus \{0\}$ (I'm thinking of a way to show this besides relying on intuition about the simpler functions that make up $f_\alpha$).

The only way to get rid of the simple pole at $0$ is to have $\alpha^2=2$, greatly restricting the values of $\alpha$ – otherwise, the integral has no hope to converge. It suffices to consider $\bar\alpha:=\sqrt2$, as $\cosh$ is an even function. As the pole has been eliminated, we know $f_{\bar\alpha}$ is holomorphic in an (arbitrarily large) open region around $0$, and thus on the closed unit ball; hence the restriction to the interval $[0,1]$ is a smooth real function of $x$, implying it is integrable.

Wolfram Alpha gives a value of $$\int_0^1 f_\bar\alpha (x)\ dx \approx -3.2988$$ for the integral.

Comment: Thanks, but it should be easier.